# Mail the recorded audio

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, avaudiorecorder

In my app i am recording audio. I want to mail the recorded audio file. I am doing like this.

MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewControlleralloc] init];
 controller.mailComposeDelegate =self ;

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

Here **url** is the path.

printf("\n mydata %d",[myData length]);

When i am printing the data length i am able to get the length.

**[controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"audio/caf" fileName:@"name"];**

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

After doing this file is attaching but when i am downloading it in my machine(Mac or windows) i am not able to play.

can any one please help me out.

Thank You

Comment: have you solved the problem whit the audio? because i have the same problem and don't know how to fix it, My audio will not play outside the app.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and finally bypassed it by just adding the file extension to the filename like so:

```
[controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"audio/caf" fileName:@"name.caf"];
```